# Copy data from one table into another new table where columns are unknown

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to copy all data from `Table1` into `Table2`.

I don't know what and how many columns are their in table 1. I mean I want to copy even column names from table 1 to table 2.

There is option like

```
 insert * 
 into #table2 
 from Table1
```

but I even can't use this because there are many select query which has already been written at past. So I have to do something like this.

```
insert * 
into #table2 
from (select * from Table1)
```

This is throwing an error

> Incorrect syntax near )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
Select * into #table2 from (select * from table1 ) as X
```

Comment: The subquery looks redundant, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mureinik The subquery is not needed always. I might not have explained the question properly, But for my case. i had to insert the data which was the output of a query that had join in 3 tables and this method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
---To copy along with data..

select * into newtable from oldtable

--to copy only schema..

select * into newtable from oldtable where 1=2
```